# Exception Filtering not working in ASP .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm not sure why my exception isn't being handled here, thought I created the Exception Filter correctly but I may have made a mistake.

Here's my Filter:

```
public class ExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IAsyncExceptionFilter, IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new
        {
            context.Exception.Message,
            context.Exception.StackTrace,
        });

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

And my Controller Action:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
[Exception]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{
    this.eventRepository.DeleteEvent(id);

    return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted);
}
```

My exception is thrown in the repository but should bubble up here? It doesn't end up getting handled anywhere, just throws. Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake with the way I ran the code, it was actually working fine but I was just not expecting Visual Studio to break on the exception.